# Append results of form submission from inside Foundation 6 reveal to outside of the modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have a Rails form that is inside of a Foundation 6 reveal modal.

```
<div class="where-i-want-to-prepend">

  <p><a data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a form</a></p>

  <div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
    <%= form_for :object do |f| %>
      <%= f.select :attribute %>
      <%= f.submit %>     
    <% end %>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

On submission of the form, I close the reveal with ajax and , and when the modal is closed, I want to prepend the submitted data to `div.where-i-want-to-prepend`, which is the containing `div` of the modal.

```
$('.new_object').submit (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $this = $(this)
  url = $this.attr('action')
  valuesToSubmit = $this.serialize()
  $.ajax url: url, type: 'post', data: valuesToSubmit, success: (data) ->
    newDetails =  "New Details"
    $this.parents('div.reveal').on 'closed.zf.reveal', ->
      $this.parents('div.where-i-want-to-prepend').prepend($(newDetails).fadeIn(2700))
    $this.parents('div.reveal').foundation('close')
```

This submitted data can't seem to make it out of the modal, but if i do something like:

```
$this.parents('div.reveal').on 'closed.zf.reveal', ->
  $this.parents('div.reveal').prepend($(newDetails).fadeIn(2700))
$this.parents('div.reveal').foundation('close')
```

The submitted data will prepend to the inside of the modal.

How do I get the submitted form data to prepend outside of the reveal modal and to the containing `div`?
Thanks.

Comment: How is it prepending to the modal div that is being hidden? I don't think that second example should be working either.

Comment: Once the form is submitted, the modal is closed, and the form details are prepended to inside the modal.  When the modal is opened again, the form details can be seen.  Any ideas on how to get it outside of the modal?

Comment: Aha, thank you for that update.
I would suggest trying to find the element on the document using `$('where-want-to-prepend')` rather than using the parent selector. There really isn't a reason for one example to work, but not the other, unless the DOM structure is wrong and the target div isn't a parent of the modal

Comment: The form information can't make it out of anywhere outside the modal, but it does work normally anywhere inside of the modal. I can't, for example, fadeOut or slide or hide anything, upon submission of the form, outside of the modal either. It is as if though the js only works inside the modal. Strange. Any ideas?

Comment: If you can upload your code to a jsfiddle where I can reproduce the error, I could take another look. Without having an example to work off, it's just guesswork and I won't be able to help.